# Override WooCommerce global template quantity-input.php for better quantity input experience on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, input-field, product-quantity

I want WooCommerce to better handle Quantity field input when using mobile devices. Instead of showing a full keyboard for user to input quantity field, I want mobile browser to show a numeric keypad instead.

I can achieve that by modifying the quantity-input.php from

```
pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>"
inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>"
```

to

```
pattern="[0-9]*"
inputmode="numeric"
```

in

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/quantity-input.php
```

But obviously modifying the php files of WooCommerce directly is a terrible idea, so I need some guidance on the best practice of such modification.

I have been using a plugin called [Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) in Wordpress and it works well. How can I put by code to my site using that?

I have found a post that mentions template files overriding in WooCommerce by using filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150835/woocommerce-overriding-the-template-through-a-plugin) but I am not familiar with that as I am new to Wordpress / WooCommerce

It seems to be the way to go is to use the filter`wc_get_template_part` and / or `woocommerce_locate_template` but I don't know how to do that.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`woocommerce_quantity_input_args`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_quantity_input.html#1234) dedicated filter hook like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'filter_quantity_input_args_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_quantity_input_args_callback( $args, $product ) {
    $args['pattern']   = '[0-9]*';
    $args['inputmode'] = 'numeric';

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or this instead two filter hooks instead *(that will have the same effect)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_pattern', 'filter_quantity_input_pattern_callback', 10, 1 );
function filter_quantity_input_pattern_callback( $input_pattern ) {
    return '[0-9]*';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_inputmode', 'filter_quantity_input_inputmode_callback', 10, 1 );
function filter_quantity_input_inputmode_callback( $inputmode ) {
    return 'numeric';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.